# Is there a way to hook or intercept CoGetClassObject and/or CoCreateInstance calls?

Tags: windows, unit-testing, com, hook, shim

I'd like to intercept the COM [CoCreateInstanceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680701%28VS.85%29.aspx) and/or [CoGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684007%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions to replace a class with a testing shim in a unit test. This will only be for a single CLSID; all others can go through unchanged. Is there a way to do this without horrible, evil hacks?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505196/spying-on-com-objects

Comment: @Shay, indeed it is. I've voted for it to be closed as a dupe, but apparently it's not enough that just the questioner votes-to-close (I don't want to delete, as it may help someone search in the future)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question is spying on COM objects. This question is for unit testing. The former attempts to solve the problem by hooking CoCreateInstance - which doesn't mean it has to be the answer. This question wants to hook CoCreateInstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you want.

If you want to detect who is loading that class or to find whether it is loaded at all you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). A call to `CoGetClassObject()` (or `CoCreateInstanceEx()`) will lead to a `HKCR\CLSID\{Class of interest id}` key being read and Process Monitor will show you what process and when does this and how successful it is.

If you want to replace an existing class with yours - compile a library with your version of class with the same class id and change the path to the COM server inside `HKCR\CLSID\{Class of interest id}` so that your library is used to serve a class with that id. You can do that manually or with regsvr32 - first register the original library, then yours to override the class of interest registartion. COM does class id -> library mapping through that key when a consumer calls `CoGetClassObject()` or `CoCreateInstanceEx()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't be messing around with the registry for this - it'll run on an automated test suite, and the class I'm intending to override is `CLSID_KnownFolderManager`, so it's probably a bad idea to override that in a system-wide manner :) In the worst case, I could instrument the code to be tested, but if there's a clean way to replace it just for one process, that would be nice.

Comment: First, you can register the original library after the test suite is run and this will restore the sanity. Second, you can register your modified library for the current user only - modify HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID. Other than that you can't do anything more or less elegant.

Answer (score 3):

There's always the `CoTreatAsClass` function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693452(VS.85).aspx

But, as you noted, it will be a system-wide replacement of the class, not a local change.

Alternatively, you could look into hooking CoCreateInstance as suggested in the post referenced by Shay Erlichmen's comment.